# java - Showing the logout button only to logged users

Tags: java, spring, maven, thymeleaf

I've searched the web for a solution, but I can't figure this out.

I'm using Spring Boot with Maven and have the
spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf dependency in my pom.xml file.

I'm trying to show the logout button, using Thymeleaf, only if the user is logged in, but this code doesn't seem to work:

```
<div th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}">
   <div class="navbar-form navbar-right">
      <a href="/logout">
            <button type="text" class="btn btn-primary navbar-right">Logout</button>       
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

It keeps showing this error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')"
```

and the line number where I have the "if" condition with thymeleaf.

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"`, but you might have to add the dependencies etc for this. I used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also, make sure to add the `SpringSecurityDialect` so that isAuthenticated and other similar expressions can be evaluated by Spring. ex:

```
@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
   SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
   engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
   engine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
   return engine;
}
```

To the html page itself, add the following to the `<html>` tag to make sure the `sec:` tag is recognized:

```
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4"
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been using springsecurity3 and that's why the isAuthenticated() method was not functional.

Answer (score 0):

This might be unorthodox. Feel free to give your constructive criticism. You can use Principal to set a variable in your controller then in your thymeleaf set an if/else up in your header/nav bar.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mypage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String mypagemethod(Principal prin, Model model)
{
    if(prin == null)
    {
        model.addAttribute("currentuser", "noBodyHome");
    }
    else
    {
        model.addAttribute("currentuser", prin.getName());
    }
    return "mypage";
}
```

in your navbar:

```
<div th:if="${currentuser} == 'noBodyHome'"> your regular bar </div>
```

logged in:

```
<div th:if="${currentuser} != 'noBodyHome'"> show prin + show logout button</div>
```

Comment: I haven't used principal for this type of problem. I saw a solution with isAuthenticated() method, but I used the wrong dependency in pom.xml