# How to remove a HTML element from thymeleaf fragments page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working with spring boot and thymeleaf .I want to remove an element from framgments page so it should be removed from all pages which use that particular fragment.

```
<header th:fragment="userHeader">
  <a href="login" id="login-ref" class="text-left">Login </a>
  <a href="#" id="logout-ref" class="text-left">Log out</a>
</header>
```

The above code is my header which is in fragments page and i insert that in every page so after the user logs in the login ref should be hide.

And the following is jquery code.

```
submitHandler : function() {
        var userData = {
                email : $("#email").val(),
                password : $("#password").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType : 'application/json',
            url : "/user/login",
            data : JSON.stringify(userData),
            dataType :'json',
            success : function(result) {
                if(result.status) {
                    $("#login-ref").hide();
                }
            },
            error : function() {
                alert("Error! please enter proper data");
            }

        });
        return false;
    }
```

Looking forward for your help please.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.  It is expected you do a little research before posting a question.  Using the first four words of your title in a search engine will help to give you ideas to get started or if it's more thmeleaf based , have a look for removing fragments from thmeleaf.  Have a go at doing something and if you get stuck with a particular piece of code, then come back with a more specific question.  As it stands, your question is too broad and therefore off topic for SO. [may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365982/java-showing-the-logout-button-only-to-logged-users)

Comment: what are you trying to do here ?

Comment: Since you already have a `$("#login-ref").hide()`, what exactly is your question? Does this approach not work for you?

Comment: Iam using userHeader fragment of thymeleaf in all user panel pages once user logs in #login-ref should be hidden from all pages I used jQuery hide() method but it dint work.